# Tipo de dado "dinamico" nao é do mesmo tipo do nativo

Tags: c#, tipagem, conversão-de-tipo, hdf5, dynamic

Estou tentando criar uma struct que tem um de seus atributos tendo seu tipo de dado dinâmico ou variado, preciso que ( ao rodar o construtor da struct) seja definido o tipo de dado dela, e deve ser igual ao nativo pois quando eu instancio ela passando um double por exemplo, esse atributo fica como o tipo "dynamic {double}" e nao "double", ele tem todas as funcionalidades do double mas o datatype dele é "estranho", tentei com object também e acontece a mesma coisa "object{double}" ao inves de "double"

Preciso que ele seja nativo pois preciso escrever um array dessa struct em um arquivo hdf5, que nao consegue escrever sendo um tipo que nao seja nativo

Minha struct:

```
struct opcSt
{
  public Int64 dt;
  public Int64 qlt;
  public dynamic vl;

  public opcSt(Int64 i, Int64 q, dynamic v)
  {
    dt = i;
    qlt = q;
    vl = v;        
  }

  public H5T.H5Type TypetoHDF5Type()
  {
    if (vl.GetType() == typeof(int))
    {
      return H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_INT;
    }
    if (vl.GetType() == typeof(Int64))
    {
      return H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_LONG;
    }
    if (vl.GetType() == typeof(float))
    {
      return H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_FLOAT;
    }
    if (vl.GetType() == typeof(double))
    {
      return H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_DOUBLE;
    }
    else { return H5T.H5Type.C_S1; }
  }
}
```

Aqui está a parte onde eu instancio no meu código a struct que foi criada

```
foreach (Opc.Ua.DataValue dv in HistoryReadEnu(m_session, details, bvnodeId))
    {

      var aux = new opcSt((Int64)dv.SourceTimestamp.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds, dv.StatusCode.Code, dv.Value);

      arrayaux.Add(aux);
    }
```

Preciso de uma forma que retorne o tipo cru (nativo) double ou sei lá, float, int, seja la qual for que passei na construtora

Aqui está uma imagem que obtive durante a depuração, que exemplifica exatamente o que estou relatando

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi bem qual o problema. Até acho que entendi o que quer fazer e tenho dúvidas se deveria fazer assim, inclusive porque ´o código está ilegível para os padrões do C#. O que é este `Opc.Ua.DataValue`, como é composto? De qualquer forma é quase certo que sequer precisa disto, quase nunca deve usar `dynamic` e já é raro precisar de `object`.

Comment: eu preciso instanciar minha struct "opcSt", que está descrita ali em cima, esse datavalue retorna um double, no caso que queria que ao instanciar minha struct "opcSt" passando um double no lugar de "vl", o tipo do mesmo mudaria de "dynamic" para "double" porém, o C# converte isso para um tipo muito estranho que é "dynamic {double}" e nao apenas "double" e assim o meu método que escreve esses registros num arquivo(que só reconhece os tipos primitivos de dados) ao receber um "object{double}" tranca e joga uma exception dizendo que nao reconhece esse tipo de dado

Comment: Um exemplo de uma maneira que tentarei contornar agora, criando uma struct para os tipos mais usados que vou ter e depois de pegar o datavalue eu instancio um array de objetos daquela struct

Comment: Meio que você repetiu o que já estava escrito, ainda me parece que não faz sentido, mas pode ser ser que não. Ou só não está claro qual o real problema. Isto provavelmente é só arquitetura errada.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Acabei gerando umas structs específicas para cada tipo de variavel que ia necessitar, até porque para gerar o arquivo HDF5 era necessario alocar um espaço específico pra cada tipo, entao optei por fazer uma classe genérica (um helper) e a partir daí instanciar o fluxo que eu precisava com base no tipo de dado que eu lia:

```
public class OpcToHdfHelper
  {
    public dynamic opcToRun;
    public void SetTypeAndWriteHdf(string bvtag, IOpcUaSession uaSession, Opc.Ua.ReadRawModifiedDetails readDetails,
                                   Opc.Ua.NodeId sourceId, H5GroupId group)
    {
       var data = HistoryReadEnu(uaSession, readDetails, sourceId);
      int i = 0;
      var p = data.ToArray()[i].Value;
      i = 1;
      while (p == null && i < 10)
  {

    p = data.ToArray()[i].Value;
    i++;
  } ;


  if (p.GetType() == typeof(int))
  {
    opcToRun = new OpcInt32(data, bvtag, group);
  }
  if (p.GetType() == typeof(Int64))
  {
    opcToRun = new OpcInt64();
  }
  if (p.GetType() == typeof(float))
  {
    opcToRun = new OpcFloat();
  }
  if (p.GetType() == typeof(double))
  {
    opcToRun = new OpcDouble(data, bvtag, group);
  }
  if(p.GetType() == typeof(string))
  {
    opcToRun = new OpcString(data, bvtag, group);
  }
  if(p.GetType() == typeof(bool))
  {
    opcToRun = new OpcBoolean(data, bvtag, group);
  }
}
```

Edit para esclarescer o porque as diferentes structs eram necessárias:

```
  struct OpcString
  {
    public Int64 dt;
    public Int64 qlt;
    public IntPtr vl;

    public OpcString(Int64 timestamp = 0, Int64 quality = 0, string value="0")
    {
      dt = timestamp;
      qlt = quality;
      vl = new IntPtr();
      vl = ConvertTo(value);
    }

    IntPtr ConvertTo(string s)
    {
      var x = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(s);
      return x;
    }

    public OpcString(IEnumerable<Opc.Ua.DataValue> dados, string bvTag, H5GroupId groupId)
{
  dt = 0;
  qlt = 0;
  vl = new IntPtr();
  GenerateHdf5(dados, bvTag, groupId);
}
public void GenerateHdf5(IEnumerable<Opc.Ua.DataValue> dados, string bvTag, H5GroupId groupId)
{
  long[] dims = new long[1];
  dims[0] = dados.Count<Opc.Ua.DataValue>();
  H5DataSpaceId dataSpaceId = H5S.create_simple(1, dims);

  string auxLen = "";
  foreach(Opc.Ua.DataValue vc in dados)
  {
    if (vc.Value != null) { 
    if(vc.Value.ToString().Length > auxLen.Length)
    {
      auxLen = vc.Value.ToString();
    }
    }
  }



  H5DataTypeId stringTypeId = H5T.create(H5T.CreateClass.STRING, -1);


  OpcString opcHelper = new OpcString();

  H5DataTypeId dataTypeId = H5T.create(H5T.CreateClass.COMPOUND, Marshal.SizeOf(opcHelper));
  H5T.insert(dataTypeId, "Timestamp", 0, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_LONG));
  H5T.insert(dataTypeId, "Quality", 8, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_LONG));
  H5T.insert(dataTypeId, "Value", 16, stringTypeId);


  var list = new List<OpcString>();
  foreach (Opc.Ua.DataValue dv in dados)
  {
    string t = "NullValue";
    if(dv.Value != null)
    {
      t = dv.Value.ToString();
    }
    OpcString aux = new OpcString((Int64)dv.SourceTimestamp.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds, dv.StatusCode.Code, t);
    list.Add(aux);
  }
  H5DataSetId bvDset = H5D.create(groupId, bvTag, dataTypeId, dataSpaceId);
  H5D.write(bvDset, dataTypeId, new H5Array<OpcString>(list.ToArray()));

  H5D.close(bvDset);
  H5S.close(dataSpaceId);

    }
  }
  struct OpcBoolean



 {
    public Int64 dt;
    public Int64 qlt;
    public bool vl;

    public OpcBoolean(Int64 timestamp = 0, Int64 quality = 0, bool value = false)
    {
      dt = timestamp;
      qlt = quality;
      vl = value;
    }


    public OpcBoolean(IEnumerable<Opc.Ua.DataValue> dados, string bvTag, H5GroupId groupId)
    {
      dt = 0;
      qlt = 0;
      vl = false;
      GenerateHdf5(dados, bvTag, groupId);
    }
    public void GenerateHdf5(IEnumerable<Opc.Ua.DataValue> dados, string bvTag, H5GroupId groupId)
    {
  long[] dims = new long[1];
  dims[0] = dados.Count<Opc.Ua.DataValue>();
  H5DataSpaceId dataSpaceId = H5S.create_simple(1, dims);




  OpcBoolean opcHelper = new OpcBoolean();

  H5DataTypeId dataTypeId = H5T.create(H5T.CreateClass.COMPOUND, Marshal.SizeOf(opcHelper));
  H5T.insert(dataTypeId, "Timestamp", 0, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_LONG));
  H5T.insert(dataTypeId, "Quality", 8, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_LONG));
  H5T.insert(dataTypeId, "Value", 16, new H5DataTypeId(H5T.H5Type.NATIVE_HBOOL));



  var list = new List<OpcBoolean>();
  foreach (Opc.Ua.DataValue dv in dados)
  {
    OpcBoolean aux = new OpcBoolean((Int64)dv.SourceTimestamp.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)).TotalSeconds, dv.StatusCode.Code, Convert.ToBoolean(dv.Value));
    list.Add(aux);
  }
  H5DataSetId bvDset = H5D.create(groupId, bvTag, dataTypeId, dataSpaceId);
  H5D.write(bvDset, dataTypeId, new H5Array<OpcBoolean>(list.ToArray()));

  H5D.close(bvDset);
  H5S.close(dataSpaceId);

}
  }
```

Comment: Já ouviu falar em generics? https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

Comment: Ouvi sim mas nao consegui implementar de uma forma que encaixasse bem na  minha situação, as minhas structs tinham metodos que dependiam do titpo do dado no qual eu estava passando, vou botar um edit ali para mostrar